# Send mail with Mapi with reply-to multiple emails

Tags: c++, mapi

I'm working with MAPI library in C++ to send emails. Now I need that the emails I send have a reply-to set to more than one email and I just can do it to one email.

I have been reading that to be able to do this I need to work with the objects FLATENTRYLIST ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815788.aspx)) and FLATENTRY ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765578.aspx)). 
My doubt is how can I store more than one FLATENTRY object in the FLATENTRYLIST. My experience in C++ is not very high so if anyone can help me I will apreciate.

Thanks in advance

Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I developed - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx?msg=3959770#xx3959770xx

Thanks Dmitry for your help.

> > When I was copying the EntryID to the FlatEntry I as copying the wrong bytes number. Here is the final code that works like a charm.

```
BOOL CMAPIMessage::SetReplyTo(LPADRLIST lpAddrList)
{
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
    SPropValue pspvReply[1];
    LPFLATENTRYLIST lpEntryList = NULL;
    BOOL bResult = false;
    CString m_strReplyToNames;

    int cb = 0; 
    int displayNameTagID = -1;
    int emailTagID = -1;
    int entryIDTagID = -1;
    int cbAllBytes = 0;

    //Get all the EntryID's bytes to initalize the FLATENTRYLIST
    for(unsigned j=0; j<lpAddrList->cEntries; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < lpAddrList->aEntries[j].cValues; i++)
        {
            if (lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[i].ulPropTag == PR_ENTRYID)
            {
                entryIDTagID = i;
            }
        }

        if (entryIDTagID >= 0)
        {
            int feBytes = CbNewFLATENTRY(lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[entryIDTagID].Value.bin.cb);

            cbAllBytes += feBytes;
            cbAllBytes += ((feBytes + 4 & ~3) - feBytes);
        }   
    }

    //Allocate a new FLATENTRYLIST with all flatentries bytes
    cb = CbNewFLATENTRYLIST(cbAllBytes);
    hRes = MAPIAllocateBuffer(cb, (LPVOID *)&lpEntryList);
    if (FAILED(hRes))
    {
        bResult = false;    
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    ZeroMemory((VOID *)lpEntryList, cb);

    // Copy the bits of the FLATENTRY into the FLATENTRYLIST.
    lpEntryList->cEntries  = lpAddrList->cEntries;

    int countBytesAdded = 0;

    for(unsigned j=0; j<lpAddrList->cEntries; j++)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < lpAddrList->aEntries[j].cValues; i++)
        {
            if (lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[i].ulPropTag == PR_TRANSMITABLE_DISPLAY_NAME)
            {
                displayNameTagID = i;
            }
            else if (lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[i].ulPropTag == PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
            {
                emailTagID = i;
            }
            else if (lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[i].ulPropTag == PR_ENTRYID)
            {
                entryIDTagID = i;
            }
        }

        if ((emailTagID>=0) && (entryIDTagID>=0))
        {
            CString m_strReplyToName;
            CString m_strReplyToEmail;

            m_strReplyToEmail=lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[emailTagID].Value.lpszA;

            if(displayNameTagID>=0) 
                m_strReplyToName=lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[displayNameTagID].Value.lpszA;
            else
                m_strReplyToName = m_strReplyToEmail;

            m_strReplyToNames += (CString)m_strReplyToName + ";";

            // Allocate a new FLATENTRY structure for the PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_ENTRIES property
            LPFLATENTRY lpReplyEntry = NULL;

            cb = CbNewFLATENTRY(lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[entryIDTagID].Value.bin.cb);
            hRes = MAPIAllocateBuffer(cb, (LPVOID *)&lpReplyEntry);
            if (FAILED(hRes))
            {
                bResult = false;    
                goto Cleanup;
            }

            ZeroMemory((VOID *)lpReplyEntry, cb);

            // Copy the bits of the entry id into the FLATENTRY structure
            CopyMemory(lpReplyEntry->abEntry, 
                lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[entryIDTagID].Value.bin.lpb, 
                                lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[entryIDTagID].Value.bin.cb);

            lpReplyEntry->cb = lpAddrList->aEntries[j].rgPropVals[entryIDTagID].Value.bin.cb;

            int missingBytes  = 0;
            int feBytes = CbFLATENTRY(lpReplyEntry);

            missingBytes = ((feBytes + 4 & ~3) - feBytes);

            //Copy each FLATENTRY to the abEntries, next to the previous added bytes
            CopyMemory(lpEntryList->abEntries + countBytesAdded, lpReplyEntry, feBytes);

            countBytesAdded += feBytes + missingBytes; 

            //Clean Memory
            if (lpReplyEntry) MAPIFreeBuffer(lpReplyEntry);
        }

        displayNameTagID = -1;
        emailTagID = -1;
        entryIDTagID = -1;
    }

    lpEntryList->cbEntries = countBytesAdded;

    pspvReply[0].ulPropTag = PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_ENTRIES;

    // Allocate memory in the lpb to hold the FLATENTRYLIST
    hRes = MAPIAllocateBuffer(CbFLATENTRYLIST(lpEntryList), (LPVOID *)&pspvReply[0].Value.bin.lpb);
    if (FAILED(hRes))
    {
        bResult = false;    
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Copy the memory into the SPropValue
    CopyMemory(pspvReply[0].Value.bin.lpb,lpEntryList,CbFLATENTRYLIST(lpEntryList));
    pspvReply[0].Value.bin.cb = CbFLATENTRYLIST(lpEntryList);

    //Set the PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES property with all names
    SetPropertyString(PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES, m_strReplyToNames);

    // Set the property that contains the FLATENTRYLIST with the reply-to adresses to the message properties
    hRes = Message()->SetProps(1,pspvReply,NULL);
    if (FAILED(hRes))
    {
        bResult = false;    
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    bResult = true; 

Cleanup:
    if (lpEntryList) MAPIFreeBuffer(lpEntryList);

    return bResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The FLATENTRYLIST has cEntries member that determines the number of the entries in the list.
You just need to store the entries in abEntries array.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, thanks for your answer.

Yes I saw those properties. The problem is that I'm not very experienced with C++ and I'm beeing unable to  find a way to set the abEntries property of the FLATENTRYLIST with more than one FLATENTRY. The code that I have right now only works for one:

lpReplyEntryList->cEntries  = 1;
lpReplyEntryList->cbEntries = CbFLATENTRY(lpReplyEntry);
CopyMemory(lpReplyEntryList->abEntries, lpReplyEntry, CbFLATENTRY(lpReplyEntry));

Can you help me with this code to make it work to more than one FLATENTRY?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a memory stream and write the FLATENTRY structures sequentially. Make sure each entry is 4 byte aligned - pad the space betwwen structures with 0 to make sure the next structure is 4 byte aligned. I do not use C++ in my MAPI code, sorry.

Comment: Thanks again Dmitry for you help. Can you post some code about this subject in other programming language?

Comment: It is a part of a commerical product, sorry... Do oy uwant to post your code that you are having problem with?